# How to downgrade a package from different server version

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have a machine that upgraded a package from "openssl:amd64 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7" to "1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.8" (dpkg.log below)

> 2021-02-24 06:18:12 upgrade openssl:amd64 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.8

How can I downgrade it to "1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7"?

Execution a "apt policy openssl" return the following output, which suggest I can only downgrade to version 1.1.0:

> openssl:
> Installed: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.8
> Candidate: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.8
> Version table:
> *** 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.8 500
> 500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
> 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
> 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
> 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4 500
> 500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: That's a security upgrade. The older version is no longer in the Ubuntu repositories. Why do you wish to revert it?

Comment: I have an app the started presenting memory leak, and, although it doesn't make sense, it started after this upgrade

Comment: If you can demonstrate that the upgrade caused a memory leak, please file a bug report immediately.

Comment: @user535733, sure thing. Actually, I just would like to downgrade it and check it the memory leak will either keep or stop